# FaviconsWebpackPlugin injects after end of HTML

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, favicon, html-webpack-plugin

As per title, `FaviconsWebpackPlugin` injects all the `<meta>` tags after the end of the document, right after the closing `</html>` tag so it obviously does not work. I have no clue how to fix it, I googled around but could find nothing else.

All icons are generated correctly, only problem is the injection.

I doubt it's a problem with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` because the JS is injected at the end of the body, and if I manually put a `favicon` config in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` it works just fine.

I'm running node `v12.6.0` on windows 10. Here are the plugins versions

```
"favicons-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
"webpack": "^4.20.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
```

Here is my relevant `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  ...
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      // favicon: './src/assets/icons/favicon.ico',
    }),
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
      logo: './src/assets/icons/big-favicon.png',
      prefix: 'icons-[hash]/',
      persistentCache: true,
      inject: true,
      background: '#fff',
      title: 'mytitle',
    }),
  ],
};
```

I'm not sure what other infos might be needed, so feel free to ask for more

Comment: I red in their notes https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin/pull/157 that by default only subset of icons has been generated in dev mode, I had same issue only one path has been generated :(